# Why the last menu item doesnt shown on iphone 5s?

Tags: iphone, wordpress

Here is website http://kamilkayalli.com/
Made on wordpress with Gantry 5
Everything ok with iphone 6 other ver of iphone 5, but iphone 5s, doesnt works properly.
The last item - phone number doesnt shown untill it clicked. Any ideas?

Comment: I see on my iPhone 5s that don't work the phone number, but there are no differente between iPhone 5 and iPhone 5s. they are some screen.

Comment: You use a Detection Mobile Device?

Comment: Honestly, I dont know it, maybe it was inlcuded in Gantry 5. The thing if paste the text there instead of numbers it's working fine. Only digits. I thought the reason in the font-family - changed to different doesnt work too((.

Comment: The px for the screen not change, the safari version not change. If you want try to change size-font or font-family but I don't think its about mobile browser.